# Как расположить div по 4 краям Left Right Top Bottom

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="controller">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Какой `div`, по каким краям? Уточните свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно расположить по углам, то я бы предложил воспользоваться такой крутой штукой, как flex.

```css
.controller {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="controller">
    <div class="container">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Либо

```css
.controller {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="controller">
    <div class="container">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Если каждая цифра должна быть расположена по центру, то можно вот так:

```css
.controller {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="controller">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="container">
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div>4</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот тут хорошая статья на тему flexbox:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

А тут можно закрепить знания в игровой форме:

http://flexboxfroggy.com/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.controller{
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 position: relative;
}
.controller > div{
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
 background: #ccc;
 padding: 10px;
}
.controller > div:nth-of-type(2),
.controller > div:nth-of-type(4){
 left: auto; right: 0;
}
.controller > div:nth-of-type(3),
.controller > div:nth-of-type(4){ 
 top: auto;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="controller">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```